# How to print and connect to printer using flutter desktop via usb?

Tags: windows, flutter, printing, printers

I want to connect to the printer via usb but I cant find any solutions to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download PDFtoPrinter.exe [http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pdftoprinter.html](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eem36/pdftoprinter.html)
2. Use it by running spwan procceses
   https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-io/Process-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package, it too easy to use:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pos_printer_platform

Answer (score 0):

you can use  printing package  https://pub.dev/packages/printing i think it would help you